# WPF listbox selection focus between observablecollection and collectionviewsource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I have two listboxes which are binding, one with an observablecollection and the other with a collectionviewsource.

with the listbox binding with the observablecollection I do not have the focus selection on the other hand with collectionviewsource yes.

I would like not to with the selection focus using the collectionviewsource but I can't find which property to act on.

For information I use the MahApp theme.

Sorry for my english.

first listbox with collectionviewsource (barrel longitudinale)

second listbox with observablecollection (barre transversale)

how to remove focus bounding box? (selectionitem "HA4")

[image]

mouse hover is good for both.

[image]

[image]

wpf code

```
<!--Barre Longitudinale-->
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <mah:MetroHeader
                        Header="Barres longitudinales"/>
                    <Separator/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox 
                    Margin="5"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CatalogueBarre}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsLongitudinale}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

                <!--Barre Transversale-->
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <mah:MetroHeader
                        Header="Barres transversales"/>
                    <Separator/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox Margin="5"
                         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding listBarre, Source={x:Static param:Catalogue.instance}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsTransversale}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

```
<!-- barre -->
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CatalogueBarre" Source="{Binding listBarre, Source={x:Static param:Catalogue.instance}}"/>

            <!-- barre longitudinale (filtre) -->
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CatalogueBarreLongitudinale" Source="{Binding listBarreLongitudinale, Source={x:Static param:Catalogue.instance}}"/>
         
            <!-- barre longitudinale (filtre) -->
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CatalogueBarreTransversale" Source="{Binding listBarreTransversale, Source={x:Static param:Catalogue.instance}}"/>
```

the only difference between the 2 lists is:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CatalogueBarre}}
ItemsSource="{Binding listBarre, Source={x:Static param:Catalogue.instance}}
```